# Jersey pojo to json conversion

Tags: xml, json, jersey, jax-rs, marshalling

Since we know Jersey uses Jaxb. I want to clear my understanding/confirmation that **for getting json** from **Object/POJO, it converts POJO to XML First and then XML to JSON**. Am i right

Does it work like this.

Actually some technical colleague of mine referred this to me. Can u guys refer me some Good Link/Article or validate above statement,... i have done effort on my end but no clear help found.

Comment: Did you check my answer and the tip from it?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is *generally* false: when converting to a MediaType (so are called the XML or JSON formats in the JAX-RS API), you have an `EntityProvider`, that is ALONE able to convert a POJO to the MediaType.

How to prove that: simply remove the `@XmlRootElemnt` (or better all JAXB annotations)  from your POJO, and you will see that the XML conversion will fail, but JSON will not (given you use [Jackson](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) and not MOXY). Of course, when using Moxy, that COULD be the case (although I really doubt that, as that could be a performance problem), but generally that is not true.

Check [the JAX-RS spec](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/), the Provider chapter for details on how such a Provider works.